# Access to Google analytic management API

Tags: javascript, python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I wish to use Google analytic management API and I have very basic problem that I am struggling with. For both Javascript and Python that I tried this [instruction](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/list#examples), it says there is no module named 'analytics'. Do I need to use some codes to connect to my Google analytic account?

```
function listFilters() {
  var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.filters.list({
   'accountId': '123456'
 });
request.execute(printFilters);
}
```

Would you please help me to know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mentions here that you need to have analytics object authorized which is why you're getting no analytics module error
http://take.ms/Gk7z6

Here's how you can get your analytics authorized object
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/list#auth
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/authorization

Here's how you can get started with the javascript api library
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js